# Can there be a response mismatch in AJAX call while getting the response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having an application in which multiple users send queries via AJAX calls and get the response from other server. Now is it possible that if a **User A** sends request for getting **ITEM 1** and at the same moment **User B** sends a request for getting **ITEM 2**, **User A** gets **ITEM 2** and **User B** gets **ITEM 1**? (Both the users have logged and have separate sessions.)
If it is possible then what I can do to stop it?

These requests are sent over to another server which is an *API* and the requests are stateless in nature. So, the *API server* does not store any thing and just sends the response for the request received. Can any one help or share a link for reference?

This is the last step I am stuck at in terms of user request-response safety before my application hits production environment.

Comment: It would be extremely rare that the AJAX (HTTP transport) or the web server to be at fault if you are seeing this behaviour.  So, in short, no this is not possible.  However, if you are actually seeing this, then please share more detail of exactly how you are reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Davin Tryon, I have not experienced this, but because of the testing team asking me to ensure that users don't get someone else's response I am worried about this. Because once this goes live there will be around 500-1000 at any given time. So just wanted to be sure.

Comment: You should run a load test and put your server under concurrent user load for a significant period of time (testing each response).  This is the only way to have evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the data retrieval code itself is thread safe (and there's no race conditions), then there should never be a mismatch in responses. It's not down to the mechanism of the AJAX call itself, it's more to do with the structure of the server code that's actually being executed.

Comment: Can you please explain about the data retrieval code part which you are talking about with a small example. And does it mean that an AJAX call with id **1** will never capture the response of AJAX call with id **2**?

Comment: @Sahil It's more for multi-threaded applications, the topic itself is a pretty verbose and interesting one (Eric Lippert has written a great article on thread safety here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: @Sahil As for capturing different responses, no that wouldn't happen in 99.9% of all scenarios.

Comment: @Sahil No problems glad I could help.